# Two background processes which depend on each other

Tags: linux, bash, process, background

In a Linux script I want to start two processes in background, which dependend on each other.

```
commandA &

commandB &
```

If `commandA` has finished, `commandB` should be killed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this sufficient?

```
commandA &
PID1=$!
commandB &
PID2=$!
wait $PID1
kill $PID2
```

Note: There is an issue if commandB finishes before commandA & the same PID gets assigned to some other new process.

Provide proper `kill -<SIGNAL>` if `SIGTERM` is not sufficient.